# Download multiple files/documents in the browser

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm trying to figure out how to download many files based upon user selection from a list of files. I'm familiar with the `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">` download attribute for individual files but the difference in this problem is you select many files from a list then select a download button. Plunker depicted below should illustrate my problem.

I'm trying to figure out in Angular/JQLite how to download a file. I've been reading up on $window but can't seem to get the download to happen.

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YVE80FPJZXH0lD0li9M8

```
angular.module('app').directive('documentList', function(){
return {
  templateUrl: 'doclistview.html',
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  controller: function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope. downloadDocuments = function() {
      getSelectedDocuments();
      _.each($scope.selectedDocuments, function (document){
        //How to download multiple files
        $window.open(document.Template, '_blank', '');
      })
    }

    function getSelectedDocuments() {
        $scope.selectedDocuments = _.where($scope.documents, {"selected": true});
    }

    //This can really be any file type but I just plucked some images online to simplify.
    $scope.documents = [
        {"FileName": "Cube Image.png", "FileType": "png", "Template": "http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png"}
        ,{"FileName": "Dice Roll", "FileType": "jpeg", "Template": "http://nathaningram.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/random-image1.jpg"}
        ,{"FileName": "RAWR!!!", "FileType": "jpeg", "Template": "http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/8600000/random-animals-animals-8676039-1600-1200.jpg"}
    ]
  }
}
```

});

I will keep tinkering but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippets/samples here as well if you choose to use an offsite resource like `plnkr`. This will better serve future visitors by having your question "self-contained".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with angular-file-saver(filesaver) to solve my problem.

Here is an updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XmyLCpwJTodBrMrW2QHZ

```
$scope. downloadDocuments = function() {
getSelectedDocuments();
_.each($scope.selectedDocuments, function (document){
  var config = {
      data: base64toBlob(document.Template, document.MimeType),
      filename: document.FileName
  }
  fileSaver.saveAs(config);
});
```

}